# How to change text alignment of individual header cells of ui-grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

[ui-grid example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOCVq.png)

Currently my grid is as shown in the image.I want to change text-alignment of first header cell to left and second header cell to center. Is there any way to do this?

Plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/1sd3QAa6V7OhrGu5ityu

Comment: Please refer the link http://embed.plnkr.co/1sd3QAa6V7OhrGu5ityu

Comment: I am trying to implement this feature in this sample code.

Comment: I updated my answer. You should use `headerCellClass` for your header definition and `cellClass` for all the cells in that column.

Comment: You are using  `headerCellTemplate: 'headerTemplate.html'` , so now write css in this html(something like `text-align : center` or `vertical-align`

Answer (score 4):

You can add `headerCellClass` property in your column definitions:

```
headerCellClass: 'text-right'
headerCellClass: 'text-center'
```

Then add this two classes in your CSS file:

```
.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: now in the current version its headerClass